# How can I return rows that meet criteria two or more days/months/quarters IN A ROW?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I'm trying to return rows where a threshold of >=10 FactCount is met two or more months IN A ROW.**

Here is an example of the output I currently have, with the query below.

How would I achieve this? If there's anything I can clarify, please leave a comment. Thank you for your input!

**Existing table**

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
( 5454, 201601, 5),
( 5454, 201602, 3),
( 5454, 201603, 11),
( 5454, 201604, 10),
( 5454, 201605, 6),
( 9987, 201601, 2),
( 9987, 201602, 0),
( 9987, 201603, 12),
( 9987, 201604, 5),
( 9987, 201605, 7)
) AS t(userid , yearmonth , factcount);
```

**Desired Output**

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| UserID | YearMonth | FactCount |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 5454   | 201601    | 5         |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 5454   | 201602    | 3         |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 5454   | 201603    | 11        |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 5454   | 201604    | 10        |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 5454   | 201605    | 6         |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    UserID
    ,YearMonth 
    ,SUM(FactCount) AS sumFact
    ,CASE WHEN  sumFact>=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FactCount_>=10_Flag
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY
    UserID
    ,YearMonth
```

Comment: Don't format this like this. Show us the input using a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`, then show us the desired output.

Comment: Can you clarify -- Are you looking for actual SQL CREATE TABLE syntax do that you can create an actual table of the example data? Because the 'input' in this case would be the example table I showed, and the desired output is the 'Return in Query?' column. I will change that to be a separate table.

Comment: I mean your input table has commutations in it, FactCount>=10, we don't need that there. If that's what you want us to use, and FactCount is irrelevant, then don't show FactCount (either way we don't need both). Also, this solution won't cross year boundaries.

Comment: See the CTAS. That's what you want when you're talking about complex queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is actually what you want...

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT userid,
    make_date(
      substring(yearmonth::text, 1, 4)::int,
      substring(yearmonth::text, 5, 2)::int,
      1
    ) AS yearmonth,
    factcount
  FROM foo
)
SELECT userid, dategroup, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    userid,
    yearmonth,
    factcount,
    count(is_reset) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY yearmonth) AS dategroup
  FROM (
    SELECT
      userid,
      yearmonth,
      factcount,
      CASE WHEN (lag(yearmonth) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY yearmonth) + '1 month'::interval)::date <> yearmonth THEN 1 END AS is_reset
    FROM t
    WHERE factcount >= 10
  ) AS t2
) AS t3
GROUP BY userid, dategroup
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

So first, in order to solve the problem of `201612` rolling into `201701` and not `201613` we need to move these to something we can work with, namely `date`

Here we convert the `yearmonth` to a date type,

```
SELECT userid,
  make_date(
   substring(yearmonth::text, 1, 4)::int,
    substring(yearmonth::text, 5, 2)::int,
    1
  ) AS yearmonth,
  factcount
FROM foo
```

I put this in a CTE because

- You shouldn't be storing dates like textual `YYYYMM`
- It's a type-modification that I do before I get into the grunt work to solve this *Island and Gaps* problem.

Next we work from the inside out..

```
SELECT
  userid,
  yearmonth,
  factcount,
  CASE WHEN (lag(yearmonth) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY yearmonth) + '1 month'::interval)::date <> yearmonth THEN 1 END AS is_reset
FROM t
WHERE factcount >= 10
```

Here we're

- selecting only rows with a `factcount>10`. This statistic you're running ignores the others.
- create a new virtual column that returns `1` if the `datemonth` does not succeed (come after) the previous row's `datemonth` column.

This will return a set like this,

```
 userid | yearmonth  | factcount | is_reset 
--------+------------+-----------+----------
   5454 | 2016-03-01 |        11 |         
   5454 | 2016-04-01 |        10 |         
   9987 | 2016-03-01 |        12 |         
   9987 | 2016-05-01 |        19 |        1
```

Then we wrap that once more, and `count()` our is_reset

```
count(is_reset) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY yearmonth) AS dategroup
```

This will return a set like this,

```
 userid | yearmonth  | factcount | dategroup 
--------+------------+-----------+-----------
   5454 | 2016-03-01 |        11 |         0
   5454 | 2016-04-01 |        10 |         0
   9987 | 2016-03-01 |        12 |         0
   9987 | 2016-05-01 |        19 |         1
```

Now we

- group by `userid`, and `dategroup`
- select count(*).

This shows you *all* users with contiguous months with a `factcount>10` regardless of year boundaries.

```
 userid | dategroup | count 
--------+-----------+-------
   5454 |         0 |     2
```

And, as an added bonus because it had to do the work anyway, it'll tell you

- how many contiguous months they had a `factcount > 10`
- if they had other groups of more than two contigious months with a factcount>10. Ie, what if they had Jan-Feb-March and Oct,Dec with factcounts of 11?

So you may see something like,

```
 userid | dategroup | count 
--------+-----------+-------
   5454 |         0 |     3
   5454 |         1 |     2
```

But, I think for your purposes you can work with that output to do whatever you want. IE, `SELECT DISTINCT userid` and then `JOIN` to the main table if you all rows from all users that have two or more contiguous months with a `factcount > 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lead` to get the factcount of the next row for each userid ordered by yearmonth. Get all the userid's whose current row's value >= 10 and the next row's value >= 10. Then select all the rows for that userid from the table.

```
select * from tbl 
where userid in (select userid
                 from (select userid, yearmonth, factcount
                      ,lead(factcount) over(partition by userid order by yearmonth) nxt_factcount
                       from tbl) x
                 where factcount >=10 and nxt_factcount >= 10
                )
```

Edit: To consider next row as the next month even when the factcount value is missing, you first need to generate all the dates and userid combinations. Generate all the required dates using `generate_series` and `cross join` it with the userid's. Then `left join` the original table on to this and check for users with consecutive factcount >= 10 atleast once.

```
with all_dates as (
SELECT dt:: date
FROM generate_series
        (date '2016-01-01' --change this series start accordingly 
        ,date '2017-12-31' --change this series end accordingly
        ,'1 month') dt
)
,all_months_count_combs as (
select  
 u.userid
,extract(year from a.dt)||'-'||extract(month from a.dt) yearmonth 
,f.factcount
,lead(f.factcount) over(partition by u.userid order by extract(year from a.dt),extract(month from a.dt)) nxt_factcount
from all_dates a
cross join (select distinct userid from foo) u
left join foo f on u.userid=f.userid
and substring(f.yearmonth,1,4)::int=extract(year from a.dt) 
and substring(f.yearmonth,5)::int=extract(month from a.dt) 
)
select * from foo 
where userid in (select distinct userid 
                 from all_months_count_combs 
                 where factcount >=10 and nxt_factcount >=10
                )
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/EJBM99095)

Comment: This doesn't actually do at all what you want. It assumes that the `lead(yearmonth)` is the next sequential month when it may not be. The question says **IN A ROW**. I take it to mean by that, that if there is two FactCount>10 for Jan, and March (nothing for Feb), that you do NOT want it to show. In this answer it would show.

Comment: This answer also does not factor in year-month roll overs. 201612, and 201704 would show if nothing existed between them.